# FluentValidation include additional data via RootContext and declare which rulessets to run

Tags: fluentvalidation

In fluentvalidation you can either send the object to validate and options specifying the rulesets to run, or you can create a validationcontext and include additional data via RootContext.  In my current situation, I need to do both.  I need to include additional data on the RootContext and specify what validations to run.  I am manually creating the validator as it is needed.  Can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

The following link explains how to setup the context, including the rule sets that need to be applied.

https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/1165

In short you create a rule set factory instance that is passed into the context constructor.

Comment: Seems kind of silly to go edit something from several months ago.  The original answer that was posted was deleted and now this one was modified.